# Default font for project from asset folder

Tags: android, fonts, xamarin, typeface

I have the following code in my `Activity` to change the font for some `ViewGroup` in a `layout`:

```
setFont("fonts/texgyreheros-regular-webfont.ttf", listBold, TypefaceStyle.Bold);
```

The definition of `setFont` is as follows:

```
private void setFont(string path, List<TextView> tTV, TypefaceStyle Type)
{
    Android.Content.Res.AssetManager mgr;
    mgr = Assets;
    Typeface font = Typeface.CreateFromAsset(mgr, path);
    for (int i = 0; i < tTV.Count; i++)
    {
        tTV[i].SetTypeface(font, Type);
    }
}
```

`listBold` is a `List<TextView>` which is populated by calling:

```
findViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.(...));
```

multiple times.

Is there any way to avoid this step by setting the default font in Android `manifest.xml` or somwhere else?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom `TextView` with your font from assets.

```
public class TextViewWithFont : TextView {
    private const string FONT = "fonts/font.ttf";

    public TextViewWithFont(Context context) : base(context) {
        SetTypeface(Typeface.CreateFromAsset(context.Assets, FONT));
    }
}
```

Then use this class in layout.

```
<com.example.views.TextViewWithFont
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Comment: thanks you very much! xamaring using c# ( not java ), but i can handle it! :)